# clear clipboard when timer timeouts

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using a timer as

```
System.Threading.Timer clipboardTimer = new Timer(ClearClipboard);
```

Next, I change its interval as

```
clipboardTimer.Change(1000, 30000);
```

In the handle timeout function, i.e. `ClearClipboard`, I want to clear the clipboard as

```
void ClearClipboard(object o)
{
    Clipboard.SetText("");
}
```

but there is `System.Unauthorised` exception. Maybe, this is because there are two different threads. So, how can I invoke clear clipboard efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the `Timer` event fires on a separate thread than the UI thread. You can change a UI element in one of two ways. The first is to tell the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) object to execute the code on the UI thread. If your object with the `Timer` is a `DependencyObject` (e.g. `PhoneApplicationPage`), you can use the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.dependencyobject.dispatcher%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property. This is done with the [`BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc190259%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

```
void ClearClipboard(object o)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Clipboard.SetText(""));
}
```

If your object is not a `DependencyObject`, you can use the [`Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.deployment%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) object to access the `Dispatcher`.

```
void ClearClipboard(object o)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Clipboard.SetText(""));
}
```

The second option is to use the [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-Silverlight,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) instead of the `Timer`. The `DispatcherTimer` event **does** fire on the UI Thread!

```
// Create the timer
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
timer.Tick += TimerOnTick;

// The subscription method
private void TimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Clipboard.SetText("");
}
```

Comment: thanks @Shawn Kendrot i've used DispatcherTimer and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

Ask `Dispatcher` to run `Clipboard.SetText("");` on UI thread, as timer's timeout event is raised on a non-UI thread and you cannot alter controls created by the UI thread from another thread

Try something like this

```
void ClearClipboard(object o)
{
   Dispatcher.Invoke( () => { Clipboard.SetText(""); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to `Invoke` the method on the GUI thread. You can do that by calling `Control.Invoke`:

```
 control.Invoke(new Action(() => control.Text = "new text")));
```